# splash screen window opacity in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt

I am devoloping an application in Python 2.6.4 and PyQt. In that application i am having a window as below

[image]

This window is a splash screen. I made the window splash screen because i dont want the window to be shown in the Task bar. Now i want to set the opacity of the window when the slider moves. The percentage of the window opacity will be the value of the slider.

[image]

The code which i wrote fro window opacity is

```
sliderValue = self.HSLD_opasity.value()
self.pendingRevCntWindow.setWindowOpacity(sliderValue)
```

My Problem is that the attribute `setWindowOpacity` is not working out with splash screen.
Please can anyone help me out from this problem. Or give another way to solve this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the [code you've written so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com), example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the value from the slider to float value ranging from (0.1 - 1) because `setWindowOpacity` will take only float value ranging from (0.1 - 1).